# How do I split some information that is on the same line in python?

Tags: python, input, text

I'm working with accelerometer and gyroscope data, and my Arduino delivers multiple data per line, that way:
`"Xacce" "Yacce" "Zacce" "Xgyr" "Ygyr" "Zgyr"`.
But I need to separate this information into different variables of strings, to make counts and generate other data.
What command should I use to separate the data?

Comment: you could use module `re` to use regex or use `string.split(some_text)` and similar methods. All depends how exactly looks this line.

Comment: Can you tell use what you're starting with and what you want in the end? Not sure what `differents var ou strings` means.

Comment: A data line will be generated for every fraction of a second, with all of this information. Each data will be included in several counts, to generate a result. However, I have another question: the result of, for example, the counts in line 2, will be used as data for the counts in line 3, and so on. For this, should I use var or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything is the same line as you post, and that you know how many variables you have and need, using an comprehension and unpack into variables could be a simple way:

```
>>> l = '"Xacce" "Yacce" "Zacce" "Xgyr" "Ygyr" "Zgyr"' #example line string
>>> x_a, y_a, z_a, x_g, y_g, z_g = [x.strip('"') for x in l.split()]
>>> x_a
'Xacce'
>>> x_g
'Xgyr'
```